# Browser compatibility of a section

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="wrapper">
    other html codes.

</section>
```

Following is my css.

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For mozilla and chrome there are no issues.But for internet explorer, the entire section moves right a little.Help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this?

Comment: Internet Explorer version is 10

Comment: You know it won't work in IE 8

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the HTML5 shiv? Although IE 10 shouldn't need this.

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Another possibility is different browsers have different default margins/padding. Try to zero them out with:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using reset.css as found from here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css ... Use this css file as the first top file in your css.. .and then rest of your css. Let us know how it goes